# SQL query for checking if the result set is only from a given set of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a good way to check for multiple combinations of conditions together? for example, if I have a COUNTRY table with id column in it and a VISITED table with country_id column in it. How can I check if every ID in VISITED table is either for 'Germany' or 'Nepal' or 'Brazil' but not from any fourth country. The VISITED IDs must be from these countries then YES otherwise NO.

```
COUNTRY
id, name
1, Germany
2, Nepal

VISITED
2
1
67

Result
NO
```

If VISITED table is like

```
VISITED
2
1

Result
YES
```

If VISITED table is like

```
VISITED
2

Result
YES
```

I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you want to define some arbitrary set of countries to check against. This set can be a subset of the country list. If all the VISITED IDs are from this set of countries then the result should be *YES* otherwise the result should be *NO*. Or the other way around, if VISITED contains any ID that is not in this set then the result should be *NO* and *YES* otherwise. Here the set is defined in the query as *GermanyId, NepalId, BrazilId*:

```
select case when exists 
     (select id from VISITED where id not in (GermanyId, NepalId, BrazilId))
     then 'NO' else 'YES' end
```

Is that what you are after?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick reply. I had to chose one as the official answer and I am choosing this because the intent, to me, is clearer in this query.

Comment: @user1451111 . . . This is the weakest answer.  It does not use the `country` table, just hard-coded values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There could be a 1000 countries in the country table but as I understand it the OP may only be interested in checking against a small subset: "... either for 'Germany' or 'Nepal' or 'Brazil' but not from any fourth country..."

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `JOIN` then subquery in `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM VISITED) > COUNT(*) THEN 'NO' ELSE 'Yes' END
FROM COUNTRY c 
JOIN VISITED v on c.id = v.id
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b13c24f3f5fc6fb751607fc1ee506ffe)

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Comment: ... but I believe that it is not what the OP intended because the country table can have many entries whereas the OP only wants to check against a subset. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One variant is to use `LEFT JOIN` and check if there are non-matching rows in `Visited`.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM
            Visited
            LEFT JOIN Country ON Country.ID = Visited.CountryID
        WHERE
            Country.ID IS NULL
    )
    THEN 'NO' 
    ELSE 'YES' 
    END AS Result
;
```